# Filter a field with concatenated values against a multi-value paramter in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a field called "ContactType" in my SQL dataset. This field has more than one value joined with a "," separator.

Lets say I have two records

```
Contact Type | RecordId
-------------|----------
A,B,C        | Record1
B,C,E        | Record2
```

Now in SSRS I have a multi-value parameter to use as a *Contact Type* filter. The options will be

- A
- B
- C
- D
- E
- F

When I select A and B from the filter I want to check if A or (OR) B present in the above records. The problem here is that the `ContactType` field is a single string of text but contains more than one value.

How can I filter the values in the `ContactType` field based on the array of values in the multi-value parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be to write a simple function using custom code. The custom code editor can be accessed from the *Report* menu.

Then use a function like this:

```vb
Function CheckContactType(ContactTypeList AS String, ContactTypeFilter AS Parameter) As Boolean
    Dim contactTypes As String() = ContactTypeList.Split(",")

    For i As Integer = 0 To (ContactTypeFilter.Count-1)
        If contactTypes.Contains(ContactTypeFilter.Value(i)) Then Return True
    Next i

    Return False
End Function
```

Then your filtering *expression* would be this:

```
=Code.CheckContactType(Fields!ContactType.Value, Parameters!ContactTypeFilterParameter)
```

and you would use the `=` operator against the *value* expression:

```
=True
```

The custom code function is making use of the .NET [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Array.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336401(v=vs.110).aspx) methods. These MSDN pages are quite good for learning more about custom code in SSRS reports:

- [How to: Add Code to a Report (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Using Custom Code References in Expressions (Reporting Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155798(SQL.100).aspx)
- [Using Custom Code in SSRS Reports for Advanced String Operations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155798(SQL.100).aspx)