# How can I parse a multi-value parameter with concatenated values in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I'm having a unique issue with SSRS which is caused by the way my database stores values. We have a picklist in the system that allows users to select multiple values. The database stores the values by concatenating the values together. For example, I select 3 codes from the picklist and they are stored in the database as IKT. When I search on my report I can select multiple values from my parameter. If I search for I, K and T it will only return values that have only I, K or T in the field. It won't return if the value is concatenated with other values.

I've tried expressions within the filter of the tablix and the dataset using nested iffs and the operator field being equal, like or IN to no avail. I keep getting an error that says failed to evaluate the FilterExpression of the DataSet. I also have tried having the parameter type within the filter set to boolean and text with no luck.

I've also tried custom code found in this posting with no luck. My issues is basically similiar to this minus the commas separating the values.

[Filter a field with concatenated values against a multi-value paramter in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404163/filter-a-field-with-concatenated-values-against-a-multi-value-paramter-in-ssrs)

Any idea on how to allow my parameter to return values that are concatenated with other values?

Any help appreciated.

thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a similar manner to the method that you saw in the other question.

First I added the following code that accepts two strings and then checks how many characters are matched in both.

```
Public Function CountMatches (byval w as String, byval s as string) AS Integer
        
        Dim wa as Char() = w.ToCharArray()
        Dim sa as Char() = s.ToCharArray()
        
        Dim count As Integer = 0

        For Each ch As Char In wa
            If Array.IndexOf(sa, ch) >= 0 Then
                count += 1
            End If
        Next
        
   CountMatches = count

End Function
```

*(forgive the code, I'm not really a VB person !)*

All we will do is use the result as a filter if the count is > 0. I decided to go for a count rather than a simple "found match" vs "no match" in case you wanted to score/rank the results by how many matches, either way it's just a bit more flexible.

At the end of the is a short GIF showing it in action but here are the basic steps.

I created some sample data using the following query

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(RowN INT IDENTITY(1,1), Codes varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('IKT'), ('ABC'), ('I'), ('K'), ('T'), ('IK'), ('KT')
SELECT * FROM @t
```

I then created a multi-value parameter called `prm1` with 6 available values (I, K, T, A, B, C)

I then added two tables to the report

The first simply dumps the dataset results with no filters just to make it easier to check the results.

The second one is exactly the same but it includes an extra column with the function result in (this column is **not** required but again, easier to debug).

The second table also has the filter applied, the same process should also work on the dataset but I have not tried that.

The filter expression is as follows.

```
=Code.CountMatches(Fields!Codes.Value, JOIN(Parameters!prm1.Value, ""))
```

Here we first pass the `Codes` field, and then we pass the all the selected parameter values `JOIN()`'d togther into a string.

[image]

That's it really.

Here's a quick GIF to show it in action (right-click and open in new tab/windows to see it full screen)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough response. I'll have to give this a try when I have time.

Comment: You're welcome. When you have chance to test it, if this answered your question, please mark it as accepted (The check mark to the left under vote up/down buttons). This helps other find similar questions that have been answered.